# How do create groups of related types for use in c# generics given that there's no `typedef`?

Tags: c#, c++, generics, typedef

As one who comes from a C++ background, I've come across the following situation:

Given that c# does not support typedefs, how do you programmatically relate types. That is to say in C++ I can store related types as typedefs for retrieval when used with templates. The same thing cannot be done in c# in the same way because of the lack of `typedef`.

For example in C++ I would:

```
template< typename T >
class Thing : public ThingBase<T>
{
   public:
       bool isRelated( T::Parent & otherThing )
       {
           T::Auxillary aux( "Yes" );            
           return aux.isValid( otherThing ) && data.isParent( otherThing );
       }
   private:
       T data;
};
```

That would work with either of the following:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public:
        typedef SomeClassParent Parent; 
        typedef FooAuxillary    Auxillary;

        bool isParent( Parent & parentObject );
};

class OtherClass
{
    public:
        typedef OtherClassParent Parent; 
        typedef BarAuxillary     Auxillary;

        bool isParent( Parent & parentObject );
};
```

While the being able to call `T::isParent` on the parameter type could be achieved with a common interface interface, building the signature for `Thing::isRelated` seems like it would be impossible without typedefs.

So, in C# what do I do to get the related interface type for T (which is T::Interface in the C++ example)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve here... is it generic constraints?

Comment: I need to get a type that is related to T in some way, in this case the interface for T. But since it's generic, I need to be able to retrieve that type programatically.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Generic constraints (and likely in this case) a second generic parameter as SLaks as indicated.

```
interface IRelated<TRelated>
{
    bool isParent(TRelated parentObject);
}

class SomeClassParent {}
class SomeClass : IRelated<SomeClassParent>
{
    bool isParent(SomeClassParent parentObject)
    {
        // your logic here
        return true;
    }
}

class Thing<T, TParent> : ThingBase<T> where T : IRelated<TParent> {}
```

To use:

```
var obj = new Thing<SomeClass, SomeClassParent>();
```

Here is another option. This one requires some runtime type checking (and allows isParent to be called with an object of any type), but it cleans up the syntax.

```
interface IRelated
{
    bool isParent<T>(T parentObject);
}

class SomeClassParent {}
class SomeClass : IRelated
{
    bool isParent<T>(T parentObject)
    {
        if (parentObject is SomeClassParent)
        {
            // your logic here
            return true;
        }
    }
}

class Thing<T> : ThingBase<T> where T : IRelated {}
```

To use:

```
var obj = new Thing<SomeClass>();
```

Comment: Passing in all related types as parameter seems like a messy solution. Perhaps it's the only way though...

Comment: Is your Parent object the same for every type?  Then you can remove the TParent generic parameter and just use IRelated<SomeBaseClass>

Comment: No, it's different for each type : / which is sort of the crux of the problem as this is a simplified example. Imagine that there's a `TParent`, `TChild`, `TThis`, `TThat`, all related to any parameter type.  The collection of required dependent types is often called `concepts` in c++ template world.

Comment: There are a lot of options for cleaning this up. If you construct the objects using a factory, you can probably use type inference to make the syntax cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common generic interface to relate the type:

```
interface IRelatedTo<TRelated> 
class Thing<T, TRelated> where T : IRelatedTo<TRelated>
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following can you clarify? what is IRelatedTo with respect to my example?